# Use input-groups in easy-admin 3

Tags: bootstrap-4, easyadmin3

I'm trying to use [input-groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups-basic) in easy-admin3, as much as I search the net, I can't find any ideas?

My question is if it is possible to add it by specifying the config from the **configureFields** method as the "**setFormTypeOption**" is used to specify certain properties and not have to create a file **file.html.twig** for this

```
      $emailFields = TextField::new('email')->setFormTypeOption("attr.maxlength", 100);

      if($pageName==Crud::PAGE_EDIT || $pageName==Crud::PAGE_NEW){
        $tagFields
          ->setFormTypeOption("attr.class", 'check-field')
          ->setFormTypeOption("attr.style", "text-transform:uppercase")

          // something like that
          //->setFormTypeOption("attr.input-group", "@example.com")
      }
```

To get something like that.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add a class or other attributes like this

```
TextareaField::new('value')->setFormTypeOptions([
        'attr' => [
            'data-ckeditor' => 'true',
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ],
    ])
    ;
```

But what you want to do needs to work with the form theme template:

To form_theme.html.twig

```
{% block value_widget -%}
    {%- if symbol -%}
        <div class="input-group">
            {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">{{ symbol|default('%') }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {%- else -%}
        {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock %}
```

To Dashboard controller

```
public function configureCrud(): Crud
{
    return Crud::new()
        ->addFormTheme('form_theme.html.twig')
    ;
}
```

Finally to your field

```
TextField::new('value')
    ->setFormTypeOptions([
        'block_name' => 'value',
    ])
    ;
```